# Finding Leverage/Hatvalue of Influential Observations

Tags: r, outliers, anomaly-detection

Two datasets: one clearly has an influential observation and the other does not. However, when I find the hatvalues and use rule of thumb tests, the first does not indicate undo leverage and the second does:

```
df1 <- dplyr::tribble(
  ~input_date,          ~input_reading,
  as.Date('2006-02-01'),         12428,
  as.Date('2006-02-17'),         12543,
  as.Date('2006-02-23'),         12555,
  as.Date('2006-03-14'),         12716,
  as.Date('2006-06-16'),         13275
)
fit1 <- lm(input_reading ~ input_date, data=df1)
hatvalues(fit1)

        1         2         3         4         5 
0.3594735 0.2625274 0.2376641 0.2002821 0.9400529
```

Notice the last observation (5). It has a hatvalue of 0.94 which is more than 2x or 3x the mean of hatvalues so it is flagged as influential.

```
df2 <- dplyr::tribble(
  ~input_date,          ~input_reading,
  as.Date('2006-02-17'),         12543,
  as.Date('2006-02-23'),         12555,
  as.Date('2006-03-14'),         12716,
  as.Date('2006-06-16'),         13275,
  as.Date('2006-07-23'),           247 # Obseravation is influential
)
fit2 <- lm(input_reading ~ input_date, data=df2)
hatvalues(fit2)

        1         2         3         4         5 
0.3833232 0.3491395 0.2641404 0.3635198 0.6398770
```

Now see the last observation, it is clearly influential but it's hatvalue is not more than 2x the average.

*Background:* The dataset is values over time. Every so often the values go wonky (anomalies, spikes, resets, go to zero). My thought is to use a for loop to calculate the regressions for every 5 data points. When I hit an anomaly, then I can write some logic to fix it.

Comment: There are some errors in your code which are either typos, or the cause of your errors. E.g. both `lm()` models use `data = df` (not `df1` or `df2`). Second, you're predicting `input_reading` not `input_value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In regression analysis an *influential point* is one whose deletion has a large effect on the parameter estimates. DFBETAS measures the difference in each parameter estimate with and without the influential point (see for example this [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/141243/how-to-manually-calculate-dfbetas)).
Here is the code for the calculation of `dfbetas` measure.

```
df1 <- structure(list(input_date = structure(1:5, .Label = c("  as.Date('2006-02-01')", 
"  as.Date('2006-02-17')", "  as.Date('2006-02-23')", "  as.Date('2006-03-14')", 
"  as.Date('2006-06-16')"), class = "factor"), input_reading = c(12428L, 
12543L, 12555L, 12716L, 13275L)), .Names = c("input_date", "input_reading"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

df1$input_date <- as.numeric(df1$input_date)
fit1 <- lm(input_reading ~ input_date, data=df1)

( dfbs1 <- dfbetas(fit1) )

#   (Intercept)    input_date
# 1  0.94689012 -7.851198e-01
# 2  0.07973496 -5.289019e-02
# 3 -0.18342246 -1.105316e-16
# 4  0.13852536 -4.594366e-01
# 5 -4.39111784  7.281845e+00
```

The plot of the `dfbetas` for the `input_date` variable is:

```
plot(1:nrow(dfbs1), dfbs1[,2], pch="+")
```

[image]

```
df2 <- structure(list(input_date = structure(1:5, .Label = c("  as.Date('2006-02-17')", 
"  as.Date('2006-02-23')", "  as.Date('2006-03-14')", "  as.Date('2006-06-16')", 
"  as.Date('2006-07-23')"), class = "factor"), input_reading = c(12543L, 
12555L, 12716L, 13275L, 247L)), .Names = c("input_date", "input_reading"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

df2$input_date <- as.numeric(df2$input_date)
fit2 <- lm(input_reading ~ input_date, data=df2)

( dfbs2 <- dfbetas(fit2) )

#   (Intercept)    input_date
# 1 -0.92324836  7.655171e-01
# 2 -0.01153703  7.652800e-03
# 3  0.10536710  4.104386e-17
# 4 -0.19892033  6.597441e-01
# 5 25.34283780 -4.202634e+01

plot(1:nrow(dfbs2), dfbs2[,2], pch="+")
```

[image]

**Conclusions.** The two influential points in the two datasets have been correctly detected by `dfbetas`.